# Using Termux on an emulator isn't possible?

Tags: android-emulator, termux

Can someone explain why isn't it possible to use Termux on an android emulator such as VMOS though it's able to fake root access? Is it just the limitation of the fake root that's provided by the emulator so that there's no way I can use Termux unless I really have to root my phone?

Comment: What error do you get when you try to install Termux? Termux runs fine even without root so if you just want to use Termux you can simply install it from Google Play Store or FDroid.

Comment: @Robert I need to access the root files that are stored in the emulator. I was trying to decrypt dex files. That's why I need root. And I don't want to root my phone, so I'm using an emulator and thought that was the best idea I got but turned out it wasn't.

Comment: VMOS does not give root access, it can just simulate a separate device but that one is different to the device itself. If you want an emulated device better directly use an PC based emulator.

Comment: @Robert Right, I understand that. I mean at least I wish to perform something in somewhere (an emulator) which has the root access and it's able to recognize termux and allow it to access and run some commands to the root files from termux. Can I do that using Nox or Bluestack? I'm not quite sure about that pc based emulator means.

Comment: I wrote PC based emulators in difference to VMOS. I don't have experience with Nox or Bluestacks, IMHO they are designed to play games not to do something meaningful with it, so I prefer emulators like Genymotion or the emulator for Android SDK (which has images without root but the non-Google images can be rooted with a little bit of effort). In an emulator you also don't need Termux because you can simply use adb.

Comment: @Robert the play store version of termux is deprecated. Please only suggest fdroid.